# $.ui is undefined even when jquery ui library is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a page with JavaScript in it that has a self-invoked function which executes when page loads. This page also includes jquery and jquery ui libraries ( first jquery is included and after that jquery ui is included).

The following JavaScript is included at end of page just before closing body tag.

In code below, even though the variables x and y correctly indicate that jquery ui exists, but within `global.method1` function the variable z is always undefined, when it should have been defined since jquery ui is loaded.

**Question**

Why is $.ui defined outside the self-invoked function as well as within the document ready event in the same self-invoked function but not within *global.method1* method?

I have a demo at following link, in which I do not see this behavior i.e. within method1 $.ui is defined: [sample runnable code](https://js.do/sun21170/jquery-ui-undefined-issue). So, its really confusing.

```
var x = $.ui;//defined

(function (global) {

     var dialogOptions;

    $(
        function () {
            var y = $.ui;//defined

            //some more code here

        }
    );

    global.method1 = function () {
        var z = $.ui; //not defined

       //some more code here
    }

    //some more code here

})(window);
```

Comment: Is something redefining $? console.log($) Are you somehow loading 2 versions of jQuery?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @epascarello, The symbol $ in method1 correctly points to jQuery since I am using jquery within method1 without errors.  I am not sure if 2 versions of jquery are there. One version I see is loaded with a script include and the other could be by the third part controls. Would that make a difference?

Comment: If 2 versions of jquery load, it can wipe away extensions you added. Look at network panel and see how many jquery requests there are.

Comment: @Sunil Thank you for clarifying that `$` is able to be referenced further down within the body of `method1`, in which case, perhaps store `$.ui` somewhere so that `z` can access that? Seems a little messy, but it would solve the problem, to my knowledge...

Comment: @epascarello, you are correct.  The third-party control was also emitting some jquery version which I found only after your comment. Thanks. Please post it so I can mark it as an answer. Why 2 versions cause this? May be they conflict?

Comment: @Twisty, I have included a link to a running sample of this in my post. Even though the sample runs well but my actual code in the application does not.

Comment: I have solved it using epascarello comment. That is the answer.

Comment: @epascarello, Thanks. your comment helped me.

Answer (score 2):

I have attempted to create a minimal example for you;

- created a snippet with the links to jQuery in a snippet.
- added some logs to the console
- added a call to the global method

All appears to be defined.  Your issue must be in code not linked in your example.

```js
var x = $.ui; //defined
console.log(`first: ${x}`);
(function(global) {

  var dialogOptions;

  $(
    function() {
      var y = $.ui; //defined
      console.log(`second: ${y}`);
      //some more code here

    }
  );

  global.method1 = function() {
    var z = $.ui; //not defined
    console.log(`third: ${z}`);
    //some more code here
  }

  //some more code here
  global.method1(); //added this call

})(window);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I was able to solve it. I also created a sample but it works without issues in sample unlike my actual code. But after some research I found that the third-party control was emitting its own version of jquery in addition to the jquery include by me. When I disabled third-party control's jquery from being emitted, then it worked.